# Rescaling/Normalizing values from 0 to 1

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to rescale/normalize the EPC column for each brand[image] for this table. This is the formula:

[image]

How can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function to calculate the minimum and maximum:

```
UPDATE tab
SET x = (x - min(x) OVER ()) / (max(x) OVER () - min(x) OVER ());
```